# Linode Alert - inbound traffic rate

Tags: cpu, vps, linode

[CPU Usage linode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX7ey.png)

How can i correct these? It's a Centos 6.7 and i am using top and htop but when i use these tools the server its fine.

And the server starts to being crazy and consumes a lot of ram, see it:

[HTOP linode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmiOh.png)

Can you help me guys? does someone have the same problem or anything? thank you in advance.

The output from mysqltuner its:

```
-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 3m 43s (11K q [52.305 qps], 107 conn, TX: 35M, RX: 1M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 98% / 2%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 2.0G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 583.2M
[--] Other process memory: 1.4G
[--] Total buffers: 168.0M global + 2.8M per thread (151 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 0B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 181.8M (9.10% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 583.2M (29.20% of installed RAM)
[!!] Overall possible memory usage with other process exceeded memory
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/11K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 3% (5/151)
[OK] Aborted connections: 1.87%  (2/107)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance
[!!] Query cache may be disabled by default due to mutex contention.
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 1K sorts)
[OK] No joins without indexes
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 63% (841 on disk / 1K total)
[!!] Thread cache is disabled
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 81% (31 open / 38 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 1% (20/1K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (12K immediate / 12K locks)
```

And mysqld.log:

```
161010 18:03:39 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
161010 18:03:39 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.50) starting as process 8737 ...
161010 18:03:39 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
161010 18:03:39 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
161010 18:03:39 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
161010 18:03:39 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
161010 18:03:39 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
161010 18:03:39 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
161010 18:03:39 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
161010 18:03:39 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
161010 18:03:39  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
161010 18:03:40 InnoDB: 5.5.50 started; log sequence number 32512613973
161010 18:03:40 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
161010 18:03:40 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
161010 18:03:40 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
161010 18:03:40 [ERROR] Missing system table mysql.proxies_priv; please run mysql_upgrade to create it
161010 18:03:40 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_current' has the wrong structure
161010 18:03:40 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_history' has the wrong structure
161010 18:03:40 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_history_long' has the wrong structure
161010 18:03:40 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_consumers' has the wrong structure
161010 18:03:40 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_instruments' has the wrong structure
161010 18:03:40 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_timers' has the wrong structure
161010 18:03:40 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'performance_timers' has the wrong structure
161010 18:03:40 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'threads' has the wrong structure
161010 18:03:40 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_by_thread_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
161010 18:03:40 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_by_instance' has the wrong structure
161010 18:03:40 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_global_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
161010 18:03:40 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_summary_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
161010 18:03:40 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_summary_by_instance' has the wrong structure
161010 18:03:40 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'mutex_instances' has the wrong structure
161010 18:03:40 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'rwlock_instances' has the wrong structure
161010 18:03:40 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'cond_instances' has the wrong structure
161010 18:03:40 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_instances' has the wrong structure
161010 18:03:40 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
161010 18:03:40 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.50'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Remi
```

Comment: The title doesn't match the content at all...? Looks completely normal to me. If you feel your VPS is too slow, you need to upgrade. Also, switch off threads in `htop` to make the output less confusing.

Comment: I receive that alert by linode and the server being slow. The Mysql connection drops too; and the consume of ram and cpu several moments its too high

Comment: It’s not really high though. My (dedicated) server is at 5 GiB memory usage (+27 GiB cache/buffers). You also only have a single CPU assigned. It’s really not that much. // If you feel your VPS is under attack, you should examine the log files of all publicly available services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the provided log

```
161010 18:03:40 [ERROR] Missing system table mysql.proxies_priv; please run mysql_upgrade to create it
```

So you have to run this command to update internal tables.

```
mysql_upgrade -pxxx
```

Comment: That’s really only part of the problem though. Also, no passwords on the command line. :)

Comment: Yep that helps me, at this point the server are fine for at least 12 hours. Thank you